# origin of the terms "domain" and "range"?

Tags: mathematics, terminology

A 1929 paper of Chittenden contains the following sentence (about the derived set operator on a space $P$):

“Thus the relation $E' = K(E)$ defines a single-valued set-valued set-function, whose range is the class of all subsets of $P,$ and whose values are also subsets of $P.$”

Since he used *range* to mean *domain* (in current terminology), it made me wonder when the currently used terms became the norm.  It evidently wasn't before 1929.

Comment: From [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics](http://jeff560.tripod.com/mathword.html): **DOMAIN** was used in 1886 by Arthur Cayley in “On Linear Differential Equations” in the *Quarterly Journal of Pure and Applied Mathematics*: “… for points $x$ within the domain of the point $a$” and **RANGE**, was used in 1865: *The Differential Calculus* by John Spare has: “It is useful to become acquainted with the methods of fully examining the entire history of a function of one or more variables, in respect to the range of values which the function and its variable may sustain, …”

Comment: For *domain*, you can see the post: [exactly-who-popularized-the-modern-definition-of-domain-and-codomain-of-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719227/exactly-who-popularized-the-modern-definition-of-domain-and-codomain-of-function)